# how to use python to open a browser page and make it on top

Tags: python, selenium

I need to use python to open a selenium browser page and make it shown as the top page. My command is:

`driver.execute_script('''window.open("https://www.abcxyzle.com", "_blank");''')`

The problem is the url portion of the command needs to be in a variable becuase my code needs iterate through many diffferent url:

The result is:(1)

if use the fullurl name: https://www.abcxyz.com",

then it works exactly right.

(2) when i replace that portion with `testurl = https://www.abcxyzle.com",`

and my command is `driver.execute_script('''window.open(testurl, "_blank");''')`

the I get the following error message

> "Message: javascript error: testurl is not defined."

I could not understand what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**try this :**

```
testurl = "https://www.google.com"
driver.execute_script(f'''window.open("{testurl}", "_blank");''')
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
```

Comment: Thanks so much! it works. I have struggled with this issue for a very long time, and I really appreciated the help.

Answer (score 0):

Python3

```py
testurl = "https://www.abcxyzle.com"
driver.execute_script(f'window.open("{testurl}");')
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
```

Python2

```py
testurl = "https://www.abcxyzle.com"
driver.execute_script('window.open("{}");'.format(testurl))
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
```

Comment: Thanks very much for helping. But by using the above command, I get "NameError: name 'testurl' is not defined. why is that? once again, very thanks!

Comment: @PChao which version? I tested them both